# WiFi problem with HP 3670 Series printer

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I had a problem with my new printer HP 3670 series. When it is connected to USB port, works perfectly, and I select the option to Configure with wireless network (with the HP device Manager)
I also did this by running

> hp-setup

in the terminal

looks like the configuration did it well (both my pc and printer are connected to the same wifi), but after that, the HP device manager didn't recognize the Printer, so I can't use it. 
I don't want to lose the wireless feature by having to connect the printer all the time to my Pc.
So, anybody could help me to figure out a solution, please?

Comment: i had been testing with _CUPS_ and i can print well, but how can i scan and make fotocopies?

Comment: can you help us a bit with a more detailed description of your printer/scanner as googling doesn't get clear hits: they talk more of a 3670 standalone scanner; thanks